# Get the filename in the code section as input while running the setup ?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

```
const
    GetFileExInfoStandard = $0;

type 
    FILETIME = record 
      LowDateTime:  DWORD; 
      HighDateTime: DWORD; 
    end; 

    WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA = record 
      FileAttributes: DWORD; 
      CreationTime:   FILETIME; 
      LastAccessTime: FILETIME; 
      LastWriteTime:  FILETIME; 
      FileSizeHigh:   DWORD; 
      FileSizeLow:    DWORD; 
    end; 

    SYSTEMTIME = record 
      Year:         WORD; 
      Month:        WORD; 
      DayOfWeek:    WORD; 
      Day:          WORD; 
      Hour:         WORD; 
      Minute:       WORD; 
      Second:       WORD; 
      Milliseconds: WORD; 
    end; 

function GetFileAttributesEx (
    FileName:            string;  
    InfoLevelId:         DWORD; 
    var FileInformation: WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA
    ): Boolean; 
external 'GetFileAttributesExA@kernel32.dll stdcall'; 

function FileTimeToSystemTime(
    FileTime:        FILETIME; 
    var SystemTime:  SYSTEMTIME
    ): Boolean; 
external 'FileTimeToSystemTime@kernel32.dll stdcall'; 

procedure InitializeWizard();
    var 
      FileInformation: WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA; 
      SystemInfo: SYSTEMTIME;     
begin
    GetFileAttributesEx('C:\Users\Gangadhar\Desktop\white_plain.gif', GetFileExInfoStandard , FileInformation); 

    FileTimeToSystemTime(FileInformation.LastWriteTime, SystemInfo); 

    MsgBox(format('%2.2d-%2.2d-%4.4d', [SystemInfo.Day, SystemInfo.Month, SystemInfo.Year]), mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```

I am using Inno setup to create custom installers, I need this to add some thing to my installer.
By this code I can able to find the last modified date of the file  , but I want to give the file name as input while running the setup.
see here

**GetFileAttributesEx('C:\Users\Gangadhar\Desktop\white_plain.gif', GetFileExInfoStandard , FileInformation);**

in this function I was passed filename as a parameter.i want to select this filename while running the setup , as like select destination folder wizard and then pass that selected filename as parameter to the above function.

any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean with *select this filename while running the setup* ? Do you mean you want to open the file dialog and let the user select the file and pass that selected file name to the function ? And, when do you want to do that ?

Comment: @TLama exactly , after wpwelcome wizard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the [`GetOpenFileName`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_getopenfilename) function, which displays a dialog box that enables the user to select an existing file. The following script shows how to display this dialog when user leaves the welcome page. If the user cancels the file selection, they will stay on the welcome page:

```
[Code]
function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
var
  FileName: String;
begin
  // allow users to go through the wizard by default
  Result := True;
  // if the user is going to leave the welcome page, then... 
  if CurPageID = wpWelcome then
  begin
    // set the initial file name
    FileName := '';
    // open the file dialog; if the user cancels it, they will stay at
    // the welcome page (I don't know if it's your intention though)
    Result := GetOpenFileName('Select the file to check', FileName, '',
      'GIF Files (*.gif)|*.gif|All Files|*.*', '');
    // if the user selected a file, then do whatever you want with it
    if Result then
    begin
      // you got the file name in FileName variable
    end;
  end;  
end;
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your requirement. You've said in your previous comment, that you want to show the open file dialog after welcome page. That's what this script does. Comments inside the script says quite clearly where you should put the rest of your code, so I don't know what you mean with that combination.

Comment: IN this installer after welcome page, if i select any file and click on next then it needs to show the selected file last modified date in the msg box.  I have gone through the components in your script initially I did not made some changes, after making those changes This is now working for me . thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Total script, may helpful to you

```
#define MyAppName "showing the last modified date of selected file or directory"
#define MyAppVersion "1.5"
#define MyAppPublisher "My company"
#define MyAppURL "http://www.example.com/"
;#define MyAppExeName "MyProg.exe"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{CD4CCA6A-5495-4132-98EE-44BC071E850B}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
CreateAppDir=no
DisableDirPage=yes
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
OutputDir=C:\Users\Gangadhar\Desktop\showing last modified date
OutputBaseFilename=last modified date of any file
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
DisableFinishedPage=yes

[Messages]
buttoninstall=&Close Application
[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"


[Code]
const
    GetFileExInfoStandard = $0;


type 
    FILETIME = record 
      LowDateTime:  DWORD; 
      HighDateTime: DWORD; 
    end; 

    WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA = record 
      FileAttributes: DWORD; 
      CreationTime:   FILETIME; 
      LastAccessTime: FILETIME; 
      LastWriteTime:  FILETIME; 
      FileSizeHigh:   DWORD; 
      FileSizeLow:    DWORD; 
    end; 

    SYSTEMTIME = record 
      Year:         WORD; 
      Month:        WORD; 
      DayOfWeek:    WORD; 
      Day:          WORD; 
      Hour:         WORD; 
      Minute:       WORD; 
      Second:       WORD; 
      Milliseconds: WORD; 
    end; 

 var
     FileInformation: WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA;
       FileName: String;
       SystemInfo: SYSTEMTIME; 



function GetFileAttributesEx (
    FileName:            string;  
    InfoLevelId:         DWORD; 
    var FileInformation: WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA
    ): Boolean; 
external 'GetFileAttributesExA@kernel32.dll stdcall';



function FileTimeToSystemTime(
    FileTime:        FILETIME; 
    var SystemTime:  SYSTEMTIME
    ): Boolean; 
external 'FileTimeToSystemTime@kernel32.dll stdcall'; 



function UpdateReadyMemo(Space, NewLine, MemoUserInfoInfo, MemoDirInfo, MemoTypeInfo,
MemoComponentsInfo, MemoGroupInfo, MemoTasksInfo: String): String;
var
  S: String;
  Months,days:tarrayofstring;
  i:integer;
begin
i:=0;
Months:=['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];
Days:=['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];
S:='';       //Modified: 22 ?June ?2013, ??04:14:00 PM   ?24 ?June ?2013, ??02:38:18 PM
S:=S+Newline;
S:=S+'Selected Filename :'+Newline+Filename+Newline+Newline;
S:=S+'Last modified date of Selected file is:  ' ;
for i:=0 to 6 do 
begin
if SystemInfo.DayOfWeek=i then
S:=S+Days[i]+', ';
end;

S:=S+inttostr(SystemInfo.Day)+'-';
//January February March April May June July August September October November December 
for i:=0 to 11 do 
begin
if SystemInfo.Month=i+1 then
S:=S+Months[i];
end;

S:=S+'-'+inttostr(SystemInfo.Year);
Result:=S;
end;




 function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  // allow users to go through the wizard by default
  Result := True;
  // if the user is going to leave the welcome page, then... 
  if CurPageID = wpWelcome then
  begin
    // set the initial file name
    FileName := '';
    // open the file dialog; if the user cancels it, they will stay at
    // the welcome page (I don't know if it's your intention though)
    Result := GetOpenFileName('Select the file to check', FileName, '',
      'ALL Files (*.*)|*.*|All Files|*.*', '');
    // if the user selected a file, then do whatever you want with it
    if Result then
    begin
    GetFileAttributesEx(format('%s', [FileName]), GetFileExInfoStandard , FileInformation);
    FileTimeToSystemTime(FileInformation.LastWriteTime, SystemInfo); 

   // MsgBox(format('LAST MODIFIED DATE OF SELECTED FILE IS : %2.d-%2.2d-%4.4d', [SystemInfo.Day, SystemInfo.Month, SystemInfo.Year]), mbInformation, MB_OK);
      // you got the file name in FileName variable
    end;
  end;  
end;
```